# Include block is not showing in django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-models

Well, i've designed something but i am not sure, how to implement
it.

**models.py**

```
class Notificaciones(models.Model):
 IDcliente = models.ManyToManyField(User)
 Tipo_de_notificaciones = ( (1,'Ofertas'),(2,'Error'),(3,'Informacion'))
 Tipo = models.IntegerField('Tipo de notificacion',choices=Tipo_de_notificaciones, default=3,)
 Nombre_not = models.CharField("Nombre de la notifiacion",max_length=50)
 Descripcion_not = HTMLField("Descripcion de la notificacion")
 Imagen_not = models.ImageField("Imagen de la notificacion",upload_to="notificaciones")
 Fecha_Caducidad_notificacion = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de caducidad de la notificacion",auto_now_add=False)
 class Meta:
     verbose_name = 'Notificacion'
     verbose_name_plural = 'Notificaciones'
 def __str__(self):
     return self.Nombre_not
```

**views.py**

```
def notifi(request):
 notifi = Notificaciones.objects.all()
 return render_to_response('app/notificaciones.html',{ 'notifi' : notifi })
```

Now I want to show the notification in a header in a lightbox, then in my layout.html, where header, footer and etc. are called. But when I call notification, it does not appear.

```
<div id="notifiaciones" class="notificaciones notificacionesTrans" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" >
    {% include 'app/notificaciones.html' %}
</div>
```

Can someone explain if I can call the notification from views or should it be done somehow else?

**URL.PY**

```
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
url(r'^social/',include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
#url(r'^s$', 'app.views.CategoriaProductoss', name='servicios'),
#url(r'^s/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'app.views.servicioscategoria', name='servicioscategoria'),
url(r'^notificaciones/$', 'app.views.notifi', name='notificaciones'),
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'app/index.html'}, name='Vulpini.co'),
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'start$', 'app.views.start', name="start"),
url(r'ajax-upload$', 'app.views.import_uploader', name="my_ajax_upload"),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
 url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

**Notificación.html**

```
<ul>
{% for  notifi in notifi %}
    <li>{{ notifi.Tipo }}
        {{ notifi.Nombre_not }}
        <img src="{{ notifi.Imagen_not }}" alt="{{ notifi.Nombre_not }}"/>
        {{ notifi.Fecha_Caducidad_notificacion }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Login Form Inside layout.html**

```
<form action="/login" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <h4>Iniciar Sesion.</h4>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="login-social">                     
                                       <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}" target="iframe">Iniciar sesion con Facebook</a>           
                                       <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.path }}" target="iframe">Iniciar sesion con Twitter</a>

                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Usuario</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input name="username" type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" />Recordar</label>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Ingresar</button>
                                    <a href="/">Registrar</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Everything seems to be ok here. Show your `app/notificaciones.html`. What about `urls`? `inclide` block is capable only to insert html, not the data from view, so you should bind it to the desired template by yourself.

Comment: @Alfredhb.q can you edit your post to show us app/notificaciones.html and your URLs.py file?

Comment: @user2719875 done, i edited the post and show my notificaciones.html and URLs.py

Comment: @Alfredhb.q Which HTML page is "<div id="notifiaciones" class="notificaciones notificacionesTrans" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" >
    {% include 'app/notificaciones.html' %}
</div>" written in? What view renders the html page? (Asking because the view you posted - notifi - renders app/notificaciones.html, which is different than the template above).

Comment: is layout.html, i am trying call notificaciones.html inside layout.html

Comment: @Alfredhb.q can you post the view which renders layout.html? You posted "def notifi(request):" which renders app/notifiaciones.html, but where is the view which renders layout.html? (Edit: Also, it's beneficial if you use '@username' when replying to a specific user - that way, the user you replied to will get notified).

Comment: @user2719875 but `layout.html` is from where i get Header and Footer, then i don't have a render to `layout.html`.

Comment: @Alfredhb.q which URL do you go to to render layout.html?

Comment: @user2719875 i am doing the next thing, when i go any page automatically i call layou.html, look so this is index.html
`{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{%  block title%}
App
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, django.contrib.auth.views.login is what renders the index.html page (as you can see from here):

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'app/index.html'}, name='Vulpini.co'),
```

The index.html page extends layout.html and layout.html includes notificaciones.html. At no point do these templates get passed the 'notifi' variable (that is why nothing shows up - because django.contrib.auth.views.login does not pass any 'notifi' variable to your template(s)). In order to accomplish what you want to do, change the URL to this:

```
url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='Vulpini.co'),
```

and then in your views.py, add this view:

```
def index(request):
 notifi = Notificaciones.objects.all()
 return render_to_response('app/index.html',{ 'notifi' : notifi })
```

Once this is done, then index.html (which extends layout.html which calls notificaciones.html) will have access to the 'notifi' variable. Then in your index.html template, you can make a form post to "/login" which uses django.contrib.auth.view.login, like this:

```
url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='Vulpini.co'),
```

and in your settings.py, set this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

to redirect back to the index.html page after logging in.

Edit: Since this is the checked off answer, I'd like to point out that another option (as chem1st said in his answer), would be to have a look at context processors here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

View chem1st's answer for more information.

Comment: ok, this works, then now i have to make a form?, and after call it in layout no?

Comment: @Alfredhb.q If you want to log a user in, then create a form in layout.html (or wherever you want) which action's to the "/login" URL (e.g. <form action="/login">). The form will then post data to "/login" (when the user submits the form) which calls the django.contrib.auth.views.login method. django.contrib.auth.views.login will then handle the logging in, and will redirect back to '/' (as stated in the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py).

Comment: i going to edit again the main ask and you can see how look like form i do.

Comment: @Alfredhb.q Yes that's good, just make sure to add "url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='Vulpini.co')," to your urls.py file so Django knows what to do when you send post data to the "/login" URL.

Comment: now i have a problem, i am not sure what it mean
when i submit the form aparece this error `Prohibido (403)
CSRF verificacion fallida. Solicitud abortada`

Comment: @Alfredhb.q That's strange, because your form does have the {% csrf_token %}. I'm not too sure why you're getting that error, but I highly suggest creating a new post and asking the question because other SO users could see it and should be able to help you out on that issue. The CSRF Validation problem is not related to Djangos 'include' template tag.

Answer (score 0):

Include and extends blocks do nothing with passing the data from view to a template. If you want to be able to get smth from a view, pass it explicitly.

You should also have look at [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), since they will allow you to globally achive the data you want.